# How to read and send java mail message wrote with Message.writeto()?

Tags: java, file, email, message

I have working code that download messages from pop3 account and process them. Now I want to write them to separate files and process at night. For that I use `Message.writeTo(FileOutputStream)` and works, I get a pile of files.

Now I want to read them and process, but can't create a Message or `MimeMessage` from file or `FileInputStream` nor there is a `Message.readFrom(FileInputStream)` method.

I can read from eml files, but creating a message with this constructor, `MimeMessage(javax.mail.Session session,java.io.InputStream is)` requires a session and I can't create a new one.

All examples online shows how to use `writeTo()`, send mail, receive mail and create mail using hard-coded data, but none says how to read from a file.

How can I instantiate a new Message from a `writeTo()` file?

Comment: Why can't you 'create a new one'? Just create a new empty session (eg `Session.getInstance(new Properties())`) if you only need to load it, or create a properly populated session if you also need to send it.

Comment: I tried to use a null session but get a NullPointerException. Didn't try with a empty session. I don't need to send the messages, only process them at night (extract the excel attachments, convert them and insert the data in the system)